# How can I create a new text file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

I made this program it takes user input and outputs it in a new text file.

```
output = input('Insert your text')
f = open("text.txt", "a")
f.write(output)
```

This code will take a users input and prints it in a new text file. But if the file already exists in the path, the python code will just append to the file. I want the code to create a new file in the path every time the program is run. So the first time the code is run it will be displayed as text.txt, and the second time it runs it should output a new file called text(1).txt and so on.

Comment: This is the logic you need to take care of. check os module and use its exits method to see if there is already a file with the same name, and then carry on accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Check if file already exists

```
import os.path 
os.path.exists('filename-here.txt')
```

If file exists then create file with another filename (eg - appending the filename with date & time or any number  etc)

Answer (score 1):

Start by checking if `test.txt` exists. If it does, with a loop, check for `test(n).txt`, with `n` being some positive integer, starting at 1.

```
from os.path import isfile

output = input('Insert your text')

newFileName = "text.txt"

i = 1
while isfile(newFileName):
    newFileName = "text({}).txt".format(i)
    i += 1

f = open(newFileName, "w")
f.write(output)
f.close()
```

Eventually, the loop will reach some `n`, for which the filename `test(n).txt` doesn't exist and will save the file with that name.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the file you are trying to create already exists. If yes, then change the file name, else write text to the file.

```
import os

output = input('Insert your text ')

filename = 'text.txt'
i = 1
while os.path.exists(filename):
    filename = 'text ('+str(i)+').txt'
    i += 1

f = open(filename, "a")
f.write(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

A problem with checking for existence is that there can be a race condition if two processes try to create the same file:

- process 1: does file exist? (no)
- process 2: does file exist? (no)
- process 2: create file for writing ('w', which truncates if it exists)
- process 2: write file.
- process 2: close file.
- process 1: create same file for writing ('w', which truncates process 2's file).

A way around this is mode `'x'` (open for exclusive creation, failing if the file already exists), but in the scenario above that would just make process 1 get an error instead of truncating process 2's file.

To open the file with an incrementing filename as the OP described, this can be used:

```
import os

def unique_open(filename):
    # "name" contains everything up to the extension.
    # "ext" contains the last dot(.) and extension, if any
    name,ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    n = 0
    while True:
        try:
            return open(filename,'x')
        except FileExistsError:
            n += 1
            # build new filename with incrementing number
            filename = f'{name}({n}){ext}'

file = unique_open('test.txt')
file.write('content')
file.close()
```

To make the function work with a context manager ("with" statement), a `contextlib.contextmanager` can be used to decorate the function and provide automatic `.close()` of the file:

```
import os
import contextlib

@contextlib.contextmanager
def unique_open(filename):
    n = 0
    name,ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    try:
        while True:
            try:
                file = open(filename,'x')
            except FileExistsError:
                n += 1
                filename = f'{name}({n}){ext}'
            else:
                print(f'opened {filename}') # for debugging
                yield file  # value of with's "as".
                break       # open succeeded, so exit while
    finally:
        file.close() # cleanup when with block exits

with unique_open('test.txt') as f:
    f.write('content')
```

Demo:

```
C:\>test.py
opened test.txt

C:\>test
opened test(1).txt

C:\>test
opened test(2).txt
```